# Jackson map a meta object to all requests

Tags: java, jackson2

I am using jackosn and spring boot.

I want to recieve a request object that contains both meta object with information such as requestId and request time, and an object data. the object data changes between the different requests. I am talking about POST, PUT requests.

For example:

```
    {
    "meta" {
       "request_id":"11111",
       "time": 12312321 
    },
    "name":"A",
    "age":29
}


{
    "meta" {
       "request_id":"22222",
       "time": 12312321 
    },
    "color":"blue"
}
```

How can I achieve this without taking all my data classes and have the extend a base class?  I do not want to do that because I do not wish to mix business data with request data.

I would like it to be something like this: define a generic request class:

```
public class ApiRequest<T> {

    protected  RequestMeta meta;

    protected  T data;
```

Where all the fields of the data will be mapped to the internal data object.
Please notice that this implementation require me to send all the business fields within a "data" JSON block and I wish them to be at the root.

Can this be done?

Regards,
Ido

Comment: And what is wrong with `ApiRequest` example you provided ?

Comment: I need to wrap all the business fields with "data":

Comment: But wouldnt it do what you just asked? Entity of `T` will be wrapped into `data` json field.

Comment: No... I want the business fields to be at the root. not wrapped with data.

Comment: Quoting: I need to wrap all the business fields with "data":  XD

Comment: Yeah... you asked what is wrong.    I want the business fields to be at the root of the json, but mapped to an internal data object.

Comment: IMHO you want to make your life harder :)

Comment: No.. my boss wants to do that ;)